# Time average value of Spin operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

From the book Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by Griffiths,. In the section 6.4.1 (weak field zeeman effect) Griffiths tells that the time average value of $S$ operator is just the projection of $S$ onto $J$ while finding the expectation value of $J+S$

$$\vec{S}_{avg}=\frac{(\vec{S}.\vec{J})\vec{J}}{J^2}$$
How to prove this?

Comment: You can use the Wiegner - Eckart's corollary for the operator $\vec{S}$ and you find the result

Comment: I very much disagree with the way Griffiths does this. The expectation value of any operator is time independent when one has energy eigenstates. So in order to explain what is meant by the time average one has to clearly define which hamiltonian is used and which states he is talking about. Griffiths does not do this so this section is very confusing. I believe that the Wigner-Eckart theorem is the only way to do this properly. In the updated (third) edition of the book Griffiths mentions this in a footnote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Wigner-Eckart corollary where the operator $\vec{S}$ is used:

$\langle JM_J|\vec{S}|JM_J \rangle = \langle J||\vec{S}||J| \rangle \langle JM_J|\vec{J}|JM_J \rangle ;$

$\langle JM_J|\vec{J}\cdot\vec{S}|JM_J \rangle =\langle J||\vec{S}||J \rangle \langle JM_J|\vec{J}^2|JM_J \rangle;$

From this one,

$\langle J||\vec{S}||J\rangle=\frac{ \langle JM_J|\vec{J}\cdot\vec{S}|JM_J\rangle}{\langle JM_J|\vec{J}^2|JM_J\rangle}$

Now, by inserting it in the first equation,

$\langle JM_J|\vec{S}|JM_J \rangle = \frac{ 
\langle JM_J|\vec{J}\cdot\vec{S}|JM_J \rangle}{\langle JM_J|\vec{J}^2|JM_J \rangle} \langle JM_J|\vec{J}|JM_J \rangle $

Generally we have

$ \vec{S}_{average} = \frac{\vec{S}\cdot\vec{J}}{\vec{J}^2} \vec{J}$

Comment: Thanks.  I have not studied Wigner Eckart corollary, I will look into it.  Definitely you answer helps.